# JavaScript: Calling a prototype returns 'not a function' error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, prototype

I've created a simple ptotype function which I wanna use to edit data attributes of elements on my web page. I'm testing it on like every version of chrome starting from 49.0.2623.112m to the newest.
The point is... It works nowhere...

I can't get this piece of code to work in my project. It seems to work fine on stackoverflow (below snippet) but it doesn't work in any of my projects I host locally on my computer. Even on blank pages with just the `body` and `a` elements, without any additional scripts.

Everytime I run this code it returns ar error `...is not a function`.

My question is:
Is it caused by some issues with an outdated browser or is it a mistake made when writing it? I'm compleately lost here. I was searching two days and found no answer..

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
Element.prototype.data = function(name, value) {
 this.setAttribute(name, value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Text</a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector('a').data('href','https://google.com');
},5000);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: @Paulpro if that was the problem, the error would have been `Cannot read property 'data' of null`

Comment: The prototype is created by a script situated before all `body` content but it's called after everything is fully loaded.
The error log in console tells that the prototype exists but is not a function...

Comment: Instead of using a Stack Snippet, since it does not reproduce the problem as you have pointed out, could you [edit] your question and provide a minimal HTML file as a code block that _does_ reproduce the problem when running locally?

Comment: Please wait a minute or two so I can change it.

Comment: I changed it. Now it's the exact copy of the code I have stored locally.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in both Firefox and Chrome latest versions. As an aside, all you are doing is making an alias for `setAttribute`. It will be used in exactly the same way. Compare `document.querySelector('a').data(k,v)` vs `document.querySelector('a').setAttribute(k,v)`. Which one needs no further investigation to understand? Which one is likely to be confused with the jquery method that has a different mode of operation? Which one is likely to lead users into accidentally overwriting important attributes? Please also consider that monkeying with built-in prototypes is bad bad bad...

Comment: i.e. Works perfectly for me when code cut'n'pasted into a local file...

Comment: So it's probably something with the computer or the browser... Keep in mind that I'm just creating these prototypes for now and I'll later bind these to a constructor function. Tho... Can you please explain me why is EVERYBODY saying that this is a bad approach?

Comment: Works for me as well, but I would second @spender s answer (using your prototype vs the native function)

Comment: It's a whole question in itself, but ["The performance hazards of Prototype mutation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation) should give you an idea of why this is frowned upon in modern JS.

Comment: Oh and also... What I wanna do later is, let's say if the user doesn't pass any parameters to the `data` prototype, it will return the list of data attributes of the element

Comment: So basically what you're saying, adding new prototypes to the global object will cause slowdowns because browsers "predict" the shape/structure ID, which is faster than reading everything. In case of modified shape, the engine would have to read it all instead of just finding the index of some property? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski Yes, that's about right. I added an answer to show you a better way of approaching this with modern JS.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the comments, [monkey-patching prototypes is considered harmful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation). By using attributes as a data-store, you may run into situations where your method overwrites important HTML attributes, and your data must be only of the `string` type.

By using `WeakMap` you can make a *standalone* function with none of these drawbacks, where the lifetime of your data is still bound to the lifetime of the element that it is "connected" to.

```js
const data = (() => {
  const map = new WeakMap();
  return (element, key, value) => {
    if (value == null) {
      const innerMap = map.get(element);
      if (innerMap) {
        return innerMap.get(key);
      }
    }
    const innerMap = map.get(element) || new Map();
    map.set(element, innerMap);
    innerMap.set(key, value);
  };
})();

const el1 = document.querySelector("#el1");
const el2 = document.querySelector("#el2");
data(el1, "hello", "world");
data(el2, "foo", {
  complex: "object"
});
console.log(data(el1, "hello")); // "world"
console.log(data(el2, "hello")); // undefined
console.log(data(el2, "foo"));   // {complex: "object"}
```

```html
<div id="el1">some element</div>
<div id="el2">some other element</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I found a way which seems like a simple solution to me. I just created a constructor function which returns the selectod object (Like Jquery's $ does) and added the prototypes to that constructor... This way the document object isn't changed in any way.